# My program does not detect the last character while printing the line with its line number in c language?

Tags: c

> Write  a  program  that  reads  lines  from  the  standard  input.  Each  line  is  printed  on  the standard output preceded by its line number. Try to write the program so that  it has no built in limit on how long a line it can handle.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int ch;
    int pos = 1;
    printf("Enter the line :\n");
    while ((ch = getchar()) != EOF)
    {
        if (pos == 1)
        {
            printf("%d\t", pos);
            pos++;
        }
        putchar(ch);
        if (ch == '\n')
            printf("%d\t", pos++);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show sample input and resulting output.

Comment: Edit your question: 1) the title should be shorter and more specific; 2) the question should be in the text; 3) you should provide the input, the output and explain why it is wrong. [I tried it and couldn't spot any problem]

Comment: the input and output is :Enter the line :
hello
brother
1 hello
2
so the brother is not printing.

Answer (score 0):

Is very easy (and faster)  using `fgets`.

Just print the line, then search for a trailing newline (`strchr` can help) and if you find it, print the number of line.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char str[2048];
    int ln = 0;

    printf("%5d) ", ++ln);
    while (fgets(str, sizeof str, stdin)) {
        printf("%s", str);
        if (strchr(str, '\n')) {
            printf("%5d) ", ++ln);
        }
    }
    puts("EOF");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

OP's code is almost there.

Keep track of *line number* and *column position*.

User input might not end with a `'\n'`.  Better to increment and print the *line number* when in *column position* 0 and data has arrived.

To avoid numeric limits, code could use a wider type than `int`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
    int ch;
    long long line_count = 0;
    long long column_position = 0;
    printf("Enter the line :\n");
    while ((ch = getchar()) != EOF) {
        if (column_position == 0) {
          printf("%lld\t", ++line_count);
        }
        column_position++;
        putchar(ch);
        if (ch == '\n') {
          column_position = 0;
        }
    }
    fflush(stdout); // insure any last line without a \n is printed before quitting
}
```